I want to change the color of just one variable, and leave the others in the colors they are in, in the multiple correspondence analysis/Rstudio
I want to change the color of just one variable, and leave the others in the colors they are in, in the multiple correspondence analysis. I have a data frame that I will specify below. I want the COURSES variable to be black and the others to be colored. And then create ellipses around the points that are close to each other, so that I can demonstrate it more clearly in the presentation. I just managed to build this script. How to go further?
I managed to generate a graph, but I want to make it more presentable. Being able to change colors of the variables, and I want create ellipses.
 test2(COURSES,CLASSES,ARRANGEMENTS,QUANTITY_CHILD, REGIONS,COLOR_FAMILY,INCOME, EDUCATION,AGE,SEX,COST)

# SCRIPT:
ACM \<- dudi.acm(test2 \[,1:11\],
scannf = FALSE)

# VIEW THE COORDINATE OF CATEGORIES

ACM$co

# VIEW THE PERCENTAGES OF THE CATEGORIES

ACM$cw

# amount of variance captured by each category, in a simple way

ACM$eig

# Variance from each dimension

perc_variance \<- (ACM$eig / sum(ACM$eig)) \* 100

# How many categories per variable

qty_categories \<- apply( test2\[,1:11\], 2, function(x) nlevels(as.factor(x)) )

# Create the df with coordinates

df_ACM \<- data.frame(ACM$co,
Variable = rep(names(qty_categories),
qty_categories) )

# Plotting the perceptual map

df_ACM %\>%
rownames_to_column() %\>%
rename(Category = 1) %\>%
mutate(Category = gsub("COURSES.","", Category),
Category = gsub("ARRANGEMENTS.","", Category),
Category = gsub("COLOR_FAMILY.","", Category),
Category = gsub("COST.","", Category),
Category = gsub("SCHOOLING.","", Category),
Category = gsub("AGE.","", Category),
Category = gsub("QTCD.","", Category),
Category = gsub("REGIONS.","", Category),
Category = gsub("INCOME.","", Category),
Category = gsub("SEX.","", Category),
Category = gsub("CLASSES.","", Category)) %\>%
ggplot(aes(x = Comp1, y = Comp2, label = Category, color = Variable)) +
geom_point() +
geom_text_repel() +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), linetype = "longdash", color = "grey48") +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), linetype = "longdash", color = "grey48") +
labs(x = paste("Dimensão 1:", paste0(round(perc_variance\[1\], 2), "%")),
y = paste("Dimensão 2:", paste0(round(perc_variance\[2\], 2), "%"))) +
theme_bw()


Please fix the code so it runs.

I can generate a good graph with this script, how can I fix it so that it generates, in addition to the graph I make, I can highlight the courses and also create an ellipse?

The script, as posted doesn't run. It fails on the first line:

test2(COURSES,CLASSES,ARRANGEMENTS,QUANTITY_CHILD, REGIONS,COLOR_FAMILY,INCOME, EDUCATION,AGE,SEX,COST)
Error in test2(COURSES, CLASSES, ARRANGEMENTS, QUANTITY_CHILD, REGIONS,  :
could not find function "test2"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/16532098

Since we don't know what your data look like, I'm creating a fake dataset
library(ade4)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)

# number of samples for synthetic data
n = 20

test2 <- data.frame(
  COURSES = factor(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE)),
  CLASSES = factor(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE)),
  ARRANGEMENTS = factor(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE)),
  QUANTITY_CHILD = factor(sample(1:4, n, replace = TRUE)),
  REGIONS = factor(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE)),
  COLOR_FAMILY = factor(sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)),
  INCOME = factor(sample(1000:10000, n, replace = TRUE)),
  EDUCATION = factor(sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)),
  AGE = factor(sample(12:18, n, replace = TRUE)),
  SEX = factor(sample(1:2, n, replace = TRUE)),
  COST = factor(sample(100:200, n, replace = TRUE))
  )

test2

ACM <- dudi.acm(test2[,1:11], scan = FALSE)
ACM$co
ACM$cw
ACM$eig

perc_variance <- (ACM$eig / sum(ACM$eig)) * 100

perc_variance

qty_categories <- apply(test2[,1:11], 2, function(x) nlevels(as.factor(x)) )

qty_categories

df_ACM <- data.frame(
  ACM$co,
  Variable = rep(names(qty_categories),
  qty_categories)
  )

df_ACM %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>%
  rename(Category = 1) %>%
  mutate(
    Category = gsub("COURSES.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("ARRANGEMENTS.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("QUANTITY_CHILD.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("COLOR_FAMILY.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("COST.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("SCHOOLING.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("AGE.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("QTCD.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("REGIONS.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("INCOME.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("EDUCATION.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("SEX.","", Category),
    Category = gsub("CLASSES.","", Category)) -> df

df

ggplot(df, aes(x = Comp1, y = Comp2, label = Category, color = Variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("black", rainbow(10)),
    breaks = c("COURSES", unique(df$Variable) %>% setdiff("COURSES")),
  ) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), linetype = "longdash", color = "grey48") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), linetype = "longdash", color = "grey48") +
  labs(x = paste("Dimensão 1:", paste0(round(perc_variance[1], 2), "%")),
    y = paste("Dimensão 2:", paste0(round(perc_variance[2], 2), "%"))) +
  theme_bw()

# same plot, but with ellipses
ggplot(df, aes(x = Comp1, y = Comp2, label = Category, color = Variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("black", rainbow(10)),
    breaks = c("COURSES", unique(df$Variable) %>% setdiff("COURSES")),
  ) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), linetype = "longdash", color = "grey48") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), linetype = "longdash", color = "grey48") +
  labs(x = paste("Dimensão 1:", paste0(round(perc_variance[1], 2), "%")),
    y = paste("Dimensão 2:", paste0(round(perc_variance[2], 2), "%"))) +
  theme_bw() +
  stat_ellipse()


Thank you, you helped me a lot. The only thing that didn't turn out as I wanted was the ellipse, perhaps because I explained it wrong. In fact, I need a circle that surrounds the points that are close, so I can better highlight the profiles that fit, based on the circles and the variables that are inside them. How can I generate this circle, do you know? The preference is to circulate the courses, so that I can demonstrate the different profiles that consume them

We don't know what your data looks like, so it's hard to tell what you expect to see. Remember that you can use the group aesthetic on stat_ellipse to create any grouping you want. For example:
data.frame(x = c(0.171, 0.143, 0.132, 0.125, 0.166, 1.987, 1.989, 1.688, 1.999, 2),
y = c(0.125, 0.182, 0.135, 0.125, 0.455, 2.501, 1.699, 2.102, 2.001, 2),
grp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
col = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)) |>
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(col))) +
geom_point() +
stat_ellipse(aes(group = grp))
